# Hiding and replacing both html content and data-attribute values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with an unordered list that is output dynamically and is already populated with a data-attribute of 'data-value'. I have no control of what is output in the backend. I need to hide some of the list elements and change the data-attribute on one of them. So, as an example I have html of the following (not the actual data!):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li data-value="1996"><a href="javascript:;">1996</a></li>
    <li data-value="1997"><a href="javascript:;">1997</a></li>
    <li data-value="1998"><a href="javascript:;">1998</a></li>
    <li data-value="1999"><a href="javascript:;">1999</a></li>
    <li data-value=""><a href="javascript:;">2000</a></li>
<ul>
```

I've then got the following jquery:

```
window.onload = function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu li[data-value="1996"]').html('YYYY');
    $('.dropdown-menu li[data-value="1996"]').attr('data-value', 'YYYY');
    $('.dropdown-menu li[data-value=""]').addClass('hideMe');
}
```

This code words and does what I want it to but it seems really messy and long winded. Is there a better way?

Comment: You could chain the `.html()` and `.attr()` calls, but other than that it's fine

Comment: Nothing much to improve, I wouldn't call it messy/long winded. You have exactly 3 operations to do, and 3 lines of code to make them happen :)

Comment: Ditto on what Rory said.  You could store the element as a variable if you wanted to save a second lookup.

Comment: Oh! That's ok then :-)
Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you can chain the first two lines and wrap it in 2 lines:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu li[data-value="1996"]').html('YYYY').attr('data-value', 'YYYY');
    $('.dropdown-menu li[data-value=""]').addClass('hideMe');
});
```

```css
.hideMe{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li data-value="1996"><a href="javascript:;">1996</a></li>
    <li data-value="1997"><a href="javascript:;">1997</a></li>
    <li data-value="1998"><a href="javascript:;">1998</a></li>
    <li data-value="1999"><a href="javascript:;">1999</a></li>
    <li data-value=""><a href="javascript:;">2000</a></li>
<ul>
```